# How do I make a nouser/nogroup so wordpress can write to files?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I host my own test server. I am using ubuntu server 14.04 with apache2 mysql and php. and i am getting this error when I try and upload a theme to my wordpress.

Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

That for some reason i can not find a working answer for this error. I do know that permissions are involved but i am also new to the whole server admining.

So any help world be great to get this fixed. Thanks in Advance.

Justin

Comment: This question is probably better suited for Super User / Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal, navigate to the parent directory of `wp-content` and use this command `sudo chmod -R a+rw wp-content`

The `-R` means to change the permission recursively(all child directories and so on)

The `a` means all user, `+rw` means `read` and `write` permission.

Comment: OK that worked for me. Now with that said will i have to do that every time I need to upload stuff to wordpress?

Comment: No need for `wp-content` but will be needed to upload to another directory that doesn't have the write permission.

Comment: If you want to revoke the read write permission use `o-rw`. `o` = others